# BusinessObjects - Count Distinct Entries

Tags: business-objects

I'm pretty new to BusinessObjects.

I have data for requests which then have a number of status against them. I have used variables to create a flag (of 1) on those with a `Status` of `First_Seen` and `Authorised`.

Now for `RequestID` some only have an `Authorised` flag, some only have a `First_Seen` flag and others have both flags.  I need to know how many `RequestID` values I have irrespective of whether they have 1 or 2 flags (not the total number of flags).

---

*Edit:*

Note that some of the `RequestID` values have multiple status.

```
RequestID  |   Status      | First_Seen_Flag   | Authorised_Flag   |
:----------|:-------------:|:-----------------:|:-----------------:|
123456     | First_Seen    |        1          |        1          |
123456     | Authorised    |        1          |        0          |
345678     | First_Seen    |        1          |        1          |
345678     | Authorised    |        0          |        1          |
987654     | First_Seen    |        1          |        0          |
765432     | Authorised    |        0          |        0          |
```

I need to count *unique* `RequestID` values where the `First_Seen_Flag` is 1 or `Authorised_Flag` is 1 or both flags are 1, bearing in mind that not all `RequestID` values have both status or have multiple i.e. `987654` which only has a single status and `765432` which only has authorized but does not have any flag on it as it did not meet the criteria to be flagged.

---

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a column doing an "AND" with both flags. Then you can count on this third column.

New column you insert should be something like below formula:

```
 =([First_Seen] = 1) and ([Authorized] = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not achieve what I was looking for.  I will try and give an example by posting another answer as comments does not allow enough characters.